# Generate HTML from looping through a JSON object [ruby/rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing, loops

I'm using the coinbase API to get a list of receiving addresses per account, which I then parse to JSON. However, I want to display these JSON elements on a webpage. How would I loop through the JSON array and generate html while I'm doing it (e.g. by appending 
 after each element to have every element on a different line)?

The json object is below, I want to print out a list of "address" attributes:

```
{"addresses":[{"address":
{"address":"1JdB88wMbd9u63rHkReuCLxaGEweaUydGA","callback_url":null,"label":null,"created_at":"2014-08-14T18:17:17-07:00"}},
{"address":{"address":"1MoaCahENJvTAnHrUUW3VgHHQd3yLzVv9G","callback_url":null,"label":null,"created_at":"2014-08-14T01:04:08-07:00"}},
{"address":{"address":"155KDpZrQN4wmMHV7ypC9ZV1fLeLdSEFAc","callback_url":null,"label":null,"created_at":"2014-08-14T01:04:06-07:00"}},
{"address":{"address":"18c6WUcgo5gJVj6QgpnH5ZX5aBhHpWSLYv","callback_url":null,"label":null,"created_at":"2014-06-19T17:28:04-07:00"}}],
"total_count":4,"num_pages":1,"current_page":1}
```

Comment: In your controller, turn the JSON into a hash. Then in your view, iterate over the objects just like you would if you grabbed the data from the database.

Answer (score 2):

You have to parse the json ([JSON Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)) into a hash:

```
require 'json'
json_response = "{\"addresses\":[{\"address\":\n{\"address\":\"1JdB88wMbd9u63rHkReuCLxaGEweaUydGA\",\"callback_url\":null,\"label\":null,\"created_at\":\"2014-08-14T18:17:17-07:00\"}},\n{\"address\":{\"address\":\"1MoaCahENJvTAnHrUUW3VgHHQd3yLzVv9G\",\"callback_url\":null,\"label\":null,\"created_at\":\"2014-08-14T01:04:08-07:00\"}},\n{\"address\":{\"address\":\"155KDpZrQN4wmMHV7ypC9ZV1fLeLdSEFAc\",\"callback_url\":null,\"label\":null,\"created_at\":\"2014-08-14T01:04:06-07:00\"}},\n{\"address\":{\"address\":\"18c6WUcgo5gJVj6QgpnH5ZX5aBhHpWSLYv\",\"callback_url\":null,\"label\":null,\"created_at\":\"2014-06-19T17:28:04-07:00\"}}],\n\"total_count\":4,\"num_pages\":1,\"current_page\":1}"
hash_response = JSON.parse(json_response)
@addresses = hash_response['addresses']
```

Then in you view, just iterate over the addresses:

```
<ul>
  <% @addresses.each do |address| %>
    <li>= address['address']['address'] </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```